# How to turn a json array into rows in postgres

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have a json array stored in my postgres database.
The json looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "operation": "U",
        "taxCode": "1000",
        "description": "iva description",
        "tax": "12"
    },
    {
        "operation": "U",
        "taxCode": "1001",
        "description": "iva description",
        "tax": "12"
    },
    {
        "operation": "U",
        "taxCode": "1002",
        "description": "iva description",
        "tax": "12"
    }
]
```

Now I need to `SELECT` the array so that any element is in a different row of the query result. So the `SELECT` statement I perform must return the data in this way:

```
 data
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{ "operation": "U", "taxCode": "1000", "description": "iva description", "tax":"12"}
{ "operation": "U", "taxCode": "1001", "description": "iva description", "tax":"12"}
{ "operation": "U", "taxCode": "1002", "description": "iva description", "tax":"12"}
```

I tried using the `unnest()` function

```sql
SELECT unnest(json_data::json)
FROM my_table
```

but it doesn't accept the `jsonb` type.

Comment: `unnest()` is for PostgreSQL's array types. [Use](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) `json_array_elements(json)` (9.3+), `jsonb_array_elements(jsonb)` (9.4+) or `json[b]_array_elements_text(json[b])` (9.4+)

Comment: Thank you. If you aswer the question I can accept it.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

I post the answer originally written by pozs in the comment section.

`unnest()` is for PostgreSQL's array types.

Instead one of the following function can be used:

- `json_array_elements(json)` (9.3+)
- `jsonb_array_elements(jsonb)` (9.4+)
- `json[b]_array_elements_text(json[b])` (9.4+)

**Example**:

```
select * from json_array_elements('[1,true, [2,false]]')
```

output value

```
 -------------
 | 1         |
 -------------
 | true      |
 -------------
 | [2,false] |
 -------------
```

[Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) where the documentation for v9.4 can be found.

Comment: its also worthwhile mentioning that the functions with the "_text" remove the annoying quotes from JSON strings

Answer (score 79):

More difficult example:

Suppose you have a table with rows containing jsonb array each and you wish to splat (or unnest) all that arrays and do some aggregate calculations on records contained in them.

Table (let it be `categories`):

```
 id | specifics (jsonb)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | [{"name": "Brand", "required": true}, {"name": "Color", "required": false}]
  2 | [{"name": "Brand", "required": false}, {"name": "Color", "required": false}]
```

So, if you want to count, how many required specifics you have, you will need to use such query:

```
SELECT specs.name, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM 
  categories, 
  jsonb_to_recordset(categories.specifics) AS specs(name jsonb, required boolean)
WHERE 
  specs.required = TRUE
  -- AND any other restrictions you need
GROUP BY specs.name
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Here `FROM x, function(x.column)` is a shortened form of a [lateral join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) which effectively joins every row from `categories` with virtual table created by `jsonb_to_recordset` function from jsonb array in that same row.

And result will be:

```
 name  | total
---------------
 Brand |     1
```

Link to DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c4xZcEgg9dsPVDtE7Keovv/0

Comment: Great example of using lateral joins

Answer (score 59):

I would suggest using the json_to_recordset command in your case. Your SQL should then be:

```
select *
from json_to_recordset('[{"operation":"U","taxCode":1000},{"operation":"U","taxCode":10001}]')
as x("operation" text, "taxCode" int);
```

The output is:

```
------------------------
|   |operation|taxCode |
------------------------
| 1 |   "U"   |   1000 |
------------------------
| 2 |   "U"   |  10001 |
------------------------
```

The columns (or JSON keys) of the example can be freely further expanded.

Comment: How it possible on object? means i want   convert  select * from json_to_recordset('{"operation":"U","taxCode":1000}') as x("operation" text, "taxCode" int);  this    but   json_to_recordset   not work

Comment: Excellent! Thanks.

Comment: @SherinGreen Doesnt make sense to convert a object to a record *SET*, what you expect exactly? Perhaps there is another solution

Comment: @SherinGreen you can use json_each_text(json) or jsonb_each_text(jsonb) - to map object as key value records. or you can wrap an object in array first to match with solution in the answer.