# Parse string as json array from Postgre

Tags: json, postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a table in PostgreSQL with 2 columns - Id and coord. 
Column "coord" - geo coordinates stored as a string in JSON format.

Example:

```
[{"lat":49.09693425316379,"lng":33.61747393628419},{"lat":49.11835977646441,"lng":33.638456496907},{"lat":49.12103137811804,"lng":33.63866144845382},{"lat":49.09694682809236,"lng":33.61746879914138},{"lat":49.08920750204137,"lng":33.61734796797724},{"lat":49.07643862058337,"lng":33.61246117651179}]
```

How to send such string as JSON Array of objects(POST request).

Entity without getters and setters

```
public class Lepcoord implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 30)
@Column(name = "tplnr")
private String tplnr;
@Size(max = 2147483647)
@Column(name = "coord")
private String coord;
```

Controller

```
@POST
@RequestMapping(value= "/lep/{voltage}", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<List<Lepcoord>> lep (@PathVariable  String voltage) 
{
    return new ResponseEntity<>(gisDaoService.lep(voltage), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And service

```
 @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List <Lepcoord> lep (String voltage) {
         Query  query = this.em.createQuery(    
             " From Lepcoord ");   
    List <Lepcoord> rez = null;
        try {
                rez = (List<Lepcoord>) query.getResultList();
            } catch (PersistenceException r) {
                return null;
            }
            return rez;
        }
```

Hibernate cant handle json type If i storeing coord as json in Postgre. May be someone knows easier way. Not to write own classes to work with Postgres json type

Comment: It's very clear what you are actually asking. How to parse? How to send over AJAX? Do you have the code of what you've already tried so we can understand the problem?

Comment: Updated my question. All is correct. But as you can see answer will be -
tplnr :"String", coord :"String". I need to send coord as json array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Hibernate so it is good to use a custom UserType which knows how to handle json.

1. create a hibernate usertype

   ```
   public class GeoJsonType implements UserType

   {

       protected static final int[] SQL_TYPES = { java.sql.Types.VARCHAR };

       @Override
       public int[] sqlTypes()
       {
           return SQL_TYPES;
       }

       @Override
       public Class returnedClass()
       {
           return GeoEntity.class;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException
       {
           if (x == y)
           {
               return true;
           }
           else if (x == null || y == null)
           {
               return false;
           }
           else
           {
               return x.equals(y);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException
       {
           return x.hashCode();
       }

       @Override
       public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, Object owner)     throws HibernateException, SQLException

       {

   //        if (rs.wasNull())
   //        {
   //            return null;
   //        }

       //this is your json stored in db

           String rsArr = rs.getString(names[0]);

           if (rsArr == null)
               return null;        
           GeoEntity detailAttr = JSON.toObject(rsArr, GeoEntity.class, null);
           return detailAttr;
       }

       @Override
       public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index) throws HibernateException, SQLException
       {
           if (value == null)
           {
               st.setNull(index, SQL_TYPES[0]);
           }
           else
           {
               //when stroing object into db convert it to json
               GeoEntity castObject = (GeoEntity) value;
               String json = JSON.toJson(castObject);
               st.setString(index, json);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException
       {
           return value;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean isMutable()
       {
           return true;
       }

       @Override
       public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException
       {
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException
       {
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException
       {
           return original;
       }

   }
   ```
2. Your Entity.java

   @Type(type = "FQN to your GeoJsonType")

   @Column(name = "geo")

   public GeoEntity getGeo()

   {

   return geo;

   }

Comment: Thank you! But can we do the same with postgresql JSON Processing Functions? May be something like this:
query = this.em.createNativeQuery(    
 "CREATE type json_type AS (lat decimal, lng decimal);" +
" SELECT tplnr, (json_array_elements(coord)).* FROM Lepcoord");

Comment: of course you can but first of all you will lose portability then you will lose HQL and have to use only nativequery  unless you extends hibernate postgresqlDialect.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres supports the `json_to_array` function that should be of help here. Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) here.
Alternatively, there is this answer on SO: [How to turn a json array into rows in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174881/how-to-turn-a-json-array-into-rows-in-postgres) that could point you in the right direction.