# How to use LIKE on elements of a JSONB array?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb, unnest

I need to search with `LIKE` or `ILIKE` - applied to elements of a `JSONB[]` column.

I can use `unnest()` to display nested `JSONB` elements separately, but I am having trouble combining that with my `LIKE` expression. My query:

```
SELECT
    UNNEST( column_jsonb[] )
FROM
    table1
WHERE
    UNNEST( column_jsonb[] ) ->> 'member_type' LIKE '%member%'
```

Results in an error:

> argument of WHERE must not return a set

How to get this right?

Comment: `UNNEST` is for expanding arrays to rows. If you're using that approach then use `UNNEST` in a subquery.

Comment: Really `jsonb[]`? Not a plain `jsonb` with a JSON array inside? (Typically makes more sense.) And `column_jsonb[]` is not a legal identifier. Please clarify your question and add your version of Postgres. `SELECT version()` helps.

Comment: Use `jsonb_array_elements` instead of `unnest` for JSON. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174881/how-to-turn-a-json-array-into-rows-in-postgres - but we need to know the *actual* schema of your table and JSON data. Can you please post some example data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's indeed a `jsonb[]` column:

```
SELECT * -- or whatever
FROM   t, unnest(jsonb_col) j
WHERE  j->>'member_type' LIKE '%member%';
```

That's an implicit `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`.

If it's a JSON array in a plain `jsonb` column (more likely):

```
SELECT *
FROM   t1, jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_col) j
WHERE  j->>'member_type' LIKE '%member%';
```

Related:

- [Query for array elements inside JSON type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-inside-json-type/22737710#22737710)