# How to use jsonb column in WHERE IN in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, jsonb

I have the following two tables in Postgres database

***employee***

| emp_id | usersname | first_name | email | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 251030 | username1 | first_name_1 | email@email.com | USA |
| 251035 | username2 | first_name_2 | email@email.com | Canada |
| 251036 | username3 | first_name_3 | email@email.com | Australia |

***employee_notifications***

| id | notification_title | users(jsonb) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | title1 | [251030,251035] |  |
| 2 | title2 | [251030,251035] |  |
| 3 | titl3 | [251030,251035] |  |

Now I need to select the employee details from the `employee` table where the values are in `users` array in `employee_notifications` table. The `users` column is of type `jsonb`

I am using the following query here :

```
SELECT emp_id,username FROM employee 
WHERE emp_id IN (
    SELECT users FROM employee_notifications WHERE id =3
)
```

When I use this, I am getting an error
`ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = jsonb`. Also please note that my `emp_id` column is of type `varchar`

How can I convert this jsonb array to a list or something and use it in the `IN` condition ?

Comment: Why using JSON for data to be queried? Far from optimal performance design..

Comment: Does this answer your question [json array into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174881/how-to-turn-a-json-array-into-rows-in-postgres)

Comment: Use a "junction table" instead of a JSON array, then it will be a simple join.

Comment: Storing numbers in `varchar` columns is also a bad decision.

Comment: I agree with all the comments here regarding the design. But the table is already existing there and I am not able to change the design as of now as it requires a lot of effort to refactor the complete application. This will be done later, but as of now, I need some workaround to get eh values.

Answer (score 0):

`users` is an array of IDs, so you can't compare it with a single integer value. You will need to use an EXISTS condition:

```
SELECT e.emp_id, e.usersname
FROM employee e
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM employee_notifications en
    WHERE en.users @> to_jsonb(e.emp_id)
)
```

If `employee.emp_id` is indeed a varchar (why?), and your JSONB contains "integer" values like this :`[251030,251035]` (why if emp_id is a string?) you need to cast the emp_id to an integer before converting it to a JSONB value:

```
SELECT e.emp_id, e.usersname
FROM employee e
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM employee_notifications en
    WHERE en.users @> to_jsonb(e.emp_id::int)
)
```

Comment: This is just returning the column names in the select statement and there is no values even though I have matching values there in the array and the employee table.

Comment: @HappyCoder: see my edit you are using inconsistent data types all over so you need to cast things back and forth